# Android addHeaderView disappears when no items in ListView

Tags: android, listview

I am using `addHeaderView` to add a view item to the top of a `ListView`. I also have a `TextView` to display a message saying there are no items in the list.

Here is the layout:

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>          

<TextView
    android:id="@android:id/empty"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="@string/list_empty"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

And the Java code:

```
final ListView listView = getListView();
final View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item_add,
            listView, false);
listView.addHeaderView(view, null, true);
```

When there are items in the ListView then the header is shown but if I delete all items in the list (except the header view) then the header view disappears.

I would like the header view to be visible in the list view whether there are items in the list or not.

Thanks,

Comment: If you don't find any other solution to the problem, you could consider using my `MergeAdapter` to replace your use of `addHeaderView()`, as I'm reasonably certain `MergeAdapter` will not suffer from this problem: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge

Comment: Good answer given here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449522/list-activity-with-header-footer-and-empty-all-visible

Comment: how did you solve that?

Comment: Here is the solution -- > http://stackoverflow.com/a/34557372/542532

Answer (score 36):

Remove the `@android:id/empty` view from your layout, or override/subclass your adapter to return false from `isEmpty()`

Comment: I guess in that case it won't show empty view when the list is empty

Comment: To state the obvious, make sure after overriding `isEmpty()` you instantiate the adapter and set it to the ListView.

Comment: What exactly are we doing here? I am suffering from this problem. What do you mean by overriding isEmpty then setting the adapter?

Answer (score 5):

From my experience (SDK version 10):

Overriding isEmpty() in the adapter makes it work.

Then, it is optional to remove the @android:id/empty view.